# using oath2 to access square inventory counts via zoho analytics

Tags: oauth-2.0, zoho, square

need to connect to zoho analytics using oath2, to access current inventory counts.

i have Client Credentials as my Grant Type, which prompts for the following:

- URL ⇀ https://connect.squareup.com/v2/inventory/batch-retrieve-counts
- Client ID ⇀ my Square Application ID
- Client Secret ⇀ my Square Application Secret
- Access Token URL ⇀ https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/authorize
- Scope ⇀ INVENTORY_READ
- Access Token Prefix / Param Name ⇀
- Send client credentials in ⇀ Body (other option: Basic Authentication Header)
- Append token in ⇀ Header (other option: Parameter)

unfortunately, i receive the following Alert Message:

> Unable to Authenticate you. Check your Authentication details and try again. Please contact our [Zoho's] support for further assistance.

Comment: Hi, we're you able to contact Zoho support for further assistance?

Comment: yes. now i get connected, via a **Grant Type** of _Authorisation Code_. however, when i pass the url

[https://connect.squareup.com/v2/inventory/batch-retrieve-counts](https://connect.squareup.com/v2/inventory/batch-retrieve-counts)

i receive the following error:

`The imported file is empty. Kindly check the file path.`

i know my inventory has items in it, several in fact. according to the square api documentation, passing no parametres should return all inventory items. any insight?

Comment: I just checked the endpoint and everything is working correctly. Please note since you are using the Zoho integration all API functions are managed by Zoho. I'd recommend reaching out to there support for questions about the integration.